# Emails sent via Automation not in Individual email results

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, email-tracking

I'm new to Marketing Cloud. I started with Journey Builder and now moving to Automation Studio.
Emails sent through a journey are synced with Contacts in Sales Cloud in the Individual Email Result related list. But emails sent through an Automation are not. Is this normal? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1):

@Rain already answered this question, check out this link:

[Synchronising tracking data back to Salesforce from Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243982/synchronising-tracking-data-back-to-salesforce-from-marketing-cloud)

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot Rachid!