# What is the average time taken to populate tracking data in Marketing cloud and "Individual Email Results" in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, email-tracking

I am working on a API triggered journey with a single email send activity. Though the trigger successfully sent the email and also received the email.

I am unable to see the trackig data neighter in Marketing cloud "My Tracking".
Nor in "Individual Email Results" in **Sales Cloud**

Comment: Check out Rain's answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243982/synchronising-tracking-data-back-to-salesforce-from-marketing-cloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frequency of updating Sales Cloud with tracking data is set in:

Sales Cloud > Marketing Cloud tab > Marketing Cloud Connector Settings > Tracking > Tracking Frequency

[image]

I believe the default is "Hourly", which means that the IER should be created within an hour of the send, given that you have checked the "Send Tracking To Sale Cloud" box in Journey Builder Email Activity:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! And thanks for sharing additional information, that there is an checkbox to enable Sales Cloud tracking under SEND FLOW.

Answer (score 0):

It takes on average **[1 hour](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_email_send_record.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)** for the Individual Email Result to be created in Sales Cloud.

That is assuming the send was done properly to a record with 18-digit SF Contact or Lead ID.